# gnuplot read data with unit

Tags: format, gnuplot

I have some data that looks as follow:

```
test      1          8377.0 ns     105.84         32
test      2          5394.4 ns      66.39         64
test      3          3962.1 ns      45.44         64
test      4          3350.9 ns      70.99        128
```

When trying to plot this, gnuplot has problems reading "8377.0 ns" because of the unit "ns".

Is there a trick to make gnuplot ignore "ns" and just take the value eg: "5394.4 ns" = "5394.4"
**UPDATE**:

script I use:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output './graph.png'

plot "<(sed -n '6,$p' data/data_32x.txt)" using 2:3:4 with errorlines
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no tricks should be needed here, columns are delimited by whitespace by default:

> The command `set datafile separator` tells `gnuplot` that data fields in
>    subsequent input files are separated by a specific character rather than by
>    whitespace.  The most common use is to read in csv (comma-separated value)
>    files written by spreadsheet or database programs. By default data fields
>    are separated by whitespace.

This means that the numbers 1,2,3,4 will be loaded as column no. 2, numbers 8377.0,... in column no. 3, and finally numbers 105.84,... in column no. 5

Comment: I think the problem is that my colums are all delimitated by tabs except 8377.0 ns that is delimitated by a whitespace

Comment: @Mikou does your script work with `using 2:3:5`? distinction between tabs and spaces shouldn't matter...

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish between spaces and tabs if you want:

```
set datafile separator "\t"
plot "file.dat" using 2:3:4 with errorlines
```

The " ns" part of the third column is silently discarded when parsing the number from it.